# How do I programmatically set focus on an element in a different component in React?

Tags: reactjs, focus, accessibility

I have a **parent** component and two child components, call them **child A** and **child B**. I want to click a button in **child A** that will set focus on an element in **child B**. More specifically, I want to set focus on the first element under the `<main>` tag in **child B**.

How do I do so? Do I have to use `React.createRef()` in the **parent** and then pass that reference to both **children** or is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if you feel it did.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a ref in the parent component like you mentioned and passing that to `child B`, and creating a function that will focus the ref and passing that to `child A` is one way of approaching it.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  ref = React.createRef();

  handleClick = () => {
    this.ref.current.focus();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildA onClick={this.handleClick} />
        <ChildB innerRef={this.ref} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function ChildA(props) {
  return <button onClick={props.onClick}>Focus</button>;
}

function ChildB(props) {
  return <input ref={props.innerRef} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```